# How to get airmon-ng on Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I recently installed a Kali Linux distribution with default toolset. I try to use airmon-ng but have no success. I had aircrack-ng package installed (it was installed from the beggining but to be sure I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt install aircrack-ng`, it didn't help). The package is just not found. `sudo apt install airmon-ng` didn't help too. How do I install and start to use airmon-ng in my installation?

Upd: here's the contents of `apt list --installed | grep aircrack`:

```
aircrack-ng/kali-rolling,now 1:1.6-4 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `aircrack-ng` is installed, you already have `airmon-ng`, but it’s in `/usr/sbin` so it’s not on regular users’ `PATH`. You typically need to run it as root:

```
sudo airmon-ng
```